# Swift. Play() and Pause() don't work on AVPlayer on the Youtube embed video (((

Tags: ios, swift, webview, youtube, youtube-api

Please tell me why tap on the play and pause buttons do not work.

I have UIButton, under the video webview, and I try to press it to pause, it does not work.

Pressing is recognized!  I checked through the print.

What could be the problem ?

Maybe the problem is in the layer?

My Control buttons are not on the video, there UNDER it, under webview.

upd: playerControl() I even put to viewDidLoad

**webView**

```
    var webView: WKWebView! = {
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return webView
    }()
```

**Button**

```
    lazy var pauseButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    let image = UIImage(named: "Pause")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .white
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapPause), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return button
}()

@objc func tapPause() {
    print("pause player")
    player?.pause()
}
```

**playerControl**

```
var player: AVPlayer?

func playerControl() {
    if let url = currentUrl {
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.webView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    playerLayer.frame = self.webView.frame
    
    player!.play()
    player!.pause()

    }
    
}
```